# Mudança de base binária para base decimal

Tags: c

Venho tentando programar um código para resolução de um exercício. Eis a questão:

Escreva um programa na linguagem C que leia uma string de tamanho qualquer contendo dígitos binários e imprima na tela o valor decimal correspondente.

A leitura da entrada deve ser feita carácter a carácter usando a função getchar().

Contudo, após de criar um código que eu achava ser melhor complexidade para o programa, percebi um problema à qual não sei resolver.
O Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
char c;
unsigned int dec=0, i=1;

do
{

    c = getchar();  

    if ( c -'0'== 1)
    {
        dec+= i;
    }

    i*=2;

}
while(c != '\n');

printf("%d\n", dec);

return 0;
}
```

O problema é que o código está lendo o número e criando um polinômio com sentido esquerda -> direita, e polinômios de mudança de base são lidos no sentido contrario. Devido o uso da função `getchar()` não sei terminar o exercício. Alguém consegue resolver este problema ?

Comment: Qual é o problema ? Os resultados não dão corretos ? No teste rápido que fiz pareceu me correto

Comment: Para alguns números o programa funciona, o problema ta na logica o programa necessita ler do último para o primeiro, e eu n consigo implementar isso

Comment: Então alguns não funciona é isso ? Pode dar um exemplo de um que não funciona ? Fica dificil de corrigir o que quer que seja sem ver um exemplo que não está correto

Comment: 254 = 11111110, 508 = 111111100, 52 = 110100

Comment: nenhum deles da o numero exato, pois  o programa le neste sentido  --->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lógica que tem funciona, mas lendo do bit de menor peso para o de maior peso. O que significa que tem de introduzir os bits ao contrário do que seria normal.

Para resolver esse problema em particular e mantendo a lógica que tem, pode guardar primeiro os bits num array, e depois percorrer esse array na direção inversa, aplicando as mesmas operações.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    unsigned int dec = 0, i = 1;

    char bits[32];
    int bit_corrente = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') { //este while so guarda os bits
        bits[bit_corrente++] = c - '0';
    }

    int j;
    for (j = bit_corrente - 1;j >= 0; --j){ //agora percorre os bits na ordem inversa
        if (bits[j] == 1){
            dec += i;
        }
        i *= 2;
    }

    printf("%d\n", dec);
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/HUSJLw)

É interessante mencionar que tem muitas formas de fazer a mesma conversão, mas esta é a mais semelhante à lógica que já tinha no código.